# Regex to find N numbers after some token in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have data that ends up in following form:

```
x='214.123123Blar=-22.0546665252602,0.977496828218,0.793335875166,30.98755066254,-0.7838067629 75,0.508399307091,0.540006004199,0.335122489689,700.696104558168ahoymatey=morestuff'
```

My python solution is simply:

```
blar = re.search("Blar=(-?\d+\.\d+)((,-?\d+\.\d+)+)", x)
blar.groups()
```

This returns:

```
('-22.0546665252602',',0.977496828218,0.793335875166,30.98755066254,-0.783806762975,0.508399307091,0.540006004199,0.335122489689,700.696104558168',',700.696104558168')
```

Is there any correction I can make to the regex that will prevent the repetition of the last number?

I realize that it's trivial to chop it off, but I would prefer to have the regex be correct. Some additional info: 'Blar=' is always the same, but the text which follows, in this example 'ahoymatey', could be anything.

The ideal solution would allow for me to specify N numbers that follow 'Blar='. But I would be thrilled if I could keep the last number from repeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-capturing embedded group

```
blar = re.search("Blar=(-?\d+\.\d+)((?:,-?\d+\.\d+)+)", x)
blar.groups()
```

('-22.0546665252602', ',0.977496828218,0.793335875166,30.98755066254,-0.7838067629')

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp is somehow correct. There's three groups (pairs of brackets) and you get indeed three groups in your match.

It's usual for a regexp to have meaningless groups. In fact a good habit is to name them in Python :

```
blar = re.search("Blar=(?P<head>-?\d+\.\d+)(?P<tail>(,-?\d+\.\d+)+)", x)
print(blar.group('head'))
print(blar.group('tail'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this as well. It's a great tip.